# In Linux, how do I log a user out after idle period, even when they are still in a program

Tags: linux, bash, logoff

I am trying to enforce a policy that logs an idle user out of a bash shell session, even when they are in an active process like a script-based menu, or vi session.

I have tried using "export TMOUT=x" where x is the number of seconds, but this only logs a user out if they are idle at the bash shell prompt.

Is there a bash script or any C code that I can run that will check what users have been idle for too long, and then stop all processes run by that user, and log them out?

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: I don't know of anything off the shelf to do that. One could write a C wrapper for bash, but you'd it would be very tricky to get signals, process groups and other environment set properly before forking off bash. You'll probably buy yourself "user acceptance" headaches even if you got it right.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible in general to detect that user did nothing on the system. In GUI one can hook up with screen-saver - because there is an X which knows everything about the session. Over SSH that is also possible to setup the idle timeout. How precisely your users access the server?

Answer (score 5):

in bash

```
w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5 | tail -n+3
```

gives you a username/idletime pair for each shell. you can set up a cronjob using this information to logout the correct people.
The idletime is the time since the last keystroke directly in the shell (and not the applications).

Comment: I think it is the wrong field you are printing. You are printing JCPU field, not IDLE field. It should be -f 1,5